# C++11 strange error with templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


struct Void{
    static constexpr int size = 0;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
class Variadic{
private:
    typedef Variadic<T0, T1> thisT;

public:
    /** Do not use this constructor */
    Variadic(T0 el0, T1 el1): value(el0), next(el1) {}

    // avoiding decltype
    typedef T0 valueT;
    T0 value;

    typedef T1 nextT;
    T1 next; // may be next pair

    /**
     * Chainable method
     */
    template<typename ValueT>
    /*constexpr*/ inline Variadic<ValueT, thisT> add(ValueT value){
        return Variadic<ValueT, thisT>(value, (*this) );
    }

};

template<typename T>
/*constexpr*/ static inline Variadic<T, Void> make_variadic(T value){
    return Variadic<T, Void>(value, Void());
}



template<typename Arg0, typename... Args>
static inline auto make_variadic(Arg0 value0, Args... values) -> decltype( fill(make_variadic<Arg0>(value0), values...) ) {
    return fill(make_variadic<Arg0>(value0), values...);
}

/*
template<typename Arg0, typename... Args>
static inline auto make_variadic(Arg0 value0, Args... values) -> decltype(fill(Variadic<Arg0, Void>(value0, Void()), values...)) {
    return fill(Variadic<Arg0, Void>(value0, Void()), values...);
}*/


template<typename T, typename Arg0, typename... Args>
static inline auto fill(T self, Arg0 value, Args... values) -> decltype(fill(self.add(value), values...)){
    return fill(self.add(value), values...);
}

template<typename T, typename Arg0>
static inline auto fill(T self, Arg0 value) -> decltype(self.add(value)){
    return self.add(value);
}



int main()
{
    auto list = make_variadic(1, 2, 3);
}
```

code as IS http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbacd7e9bec149f0

And when I try to compile it with gcc 4.8 I get following error:

> expansion pattern '#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#

Is this http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1433 or https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51501 ?

Or this is something completly different?

Comment: How do you call your compiler?

Comment: I believe that `static inline auto fill(T self, Arg0 value, Args... values) -> decltype(fill(self.add(value), values...))` could not compile, because it is a recursive declaration. The return type of the function can not be the decltype of the return type of the function itself.

Comment: see full code here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbacd7e9bec149f0

Comment: @Klaus - really? Where you read that?

Comment: @BЈовић - Oh, indeed, that crush whole thing.

Comment: decltype can only evaluate a already defined expression. During the definition of a template function the function itself is not defined. Sorry, I could not point you to the spec.

Comment: @Klaus - And make_variadic with one argument ALREADY defined.

Comment: @Klaus Anyway, decltype can call function recursively. Can provide proof code, if you will.

Comment: @BЈовић Than, why coliru can't? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbacd7e9bec149f0

Comment: I just looked at code in your question, didn't follow links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for your error message, this looks related to a [**compiler bug**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59481) that was reduced to a [**known Defect Report**](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1433) concerning the trailing return type:

> **1433. trailing-return-type and point of declaration**
>
> Section: 3.3.2  [basic.scope.pdecl]     Status: extension
> Submitter: Jason Merrill     Date: 2011-12-20 This seems like it
> should be well-formed:
>
> ```
> template <class T> T list(T x);
>
> template <class H, class ...T>
> auto list(H h, T ...args) -> decltype(list(args...));
>
>
> auto list3 = list(1, 2, 3);
> ```
>
> but it isn't, because the second list isn't in scope in its own trailing-return-type; the point of
> declaration is after the declarator, which includes the
> trailing-return-type. And since int has no associated namespaces, the
> call in the return type only sees the first list. G++, EDG and Clang
> all reject the testcase on this basis.
>
> But this seems like a natural pattern for writing variadic function
> templates, and we could support it by moving the point of declaration
> to the ->. This would mean having to deal with a function that only
> has a placeholder for a return type, but I think we can handle that.
>
> Rationale (February, 2012):
>
> This is a request for an extension to the language and is thus more
> appropriately addressed by EWG.

Comment: I thought about it too, as I describe in question http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1433 . But ... why "fill" works ok than? It has the same variadic params...

Comment: sorry I missed that in your Q (browser didn't refresh). OTOH, Clang does compile your code on Coliru (if you disable the warning on the unused `list` variable).

Comment: Yep it compiles, so I made a bug on gcc bugzilla https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61178, just to be sure :)